# Solid state, closed packed structures, BCC lattice

Tags: physical-chemistry, crystal-structure

How many next nearest neighborhood respectively each potassium has in bcc lattice?

Comment: I am just not able to proceed, I know how to find first nearest neighbours but don't know how to find second nearest neighbors

Comment: Well, second nearest neighbors are the neighbors of the first nearest neighbors, not counting those that are already first nearest. You get there by looking at one unit cell of bcc and imagining the next unit cells out and which atom(s) in those cells are closest.

Comment: BCC is the very case when the distinction between "first nearest" and "second nearest" does not work really well. However, a line still can be drawn between the two. How many first nearest neighbors did you find, to begin with?

Comment: You're overthinking the problem. I'll give you a hint. I paint one particular "molecule" of potassium red. How many atoms are in a "molecule" of potassium metal? How many nearest neighbors does my red "molecule" have?

Comment: I find 8 first nearest atoms

Comment: You need to remember that the BCC is an abstraction within the "infinite" bulk solid. All the atoms are the same in K metal and EVERY atom is at the center of a BCC. Thinking about the "edges" of a chunk of K metal will get you into trouble.

Comment: @JonCuster Your comment is somewhat misleading. Let's consider a **square planar** lattice with parameter 1. The first nearest neighbors (all 4 of them) will be at distance 1. Now let's look at the first neighbors of first neighbors, excluding the atom at origin itself. Some of them will be at distance 2, and some at $\sqrt2$. Surely not all of them are the next nearest neighbors.

Comment: Yes not all of them are next nearest but it gives some idea about which atom is second nearest

Answer (score 1):

Second nearest neighbors are the neighbors of the first neighbors. So for BCC let's consider the atom at the body centre, for this atom the atom at the corner are nearest and for the atoms at the corners the atom at body centres of other cubes are nearest. Little imagination(there are 6 body centred atoms surrounding the atom we are considering) and counting gives the answer as six.